# Is it legal to overload a function template with another function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, function-templates

I'm trying to create an overloaded method, where both are templated.  One takes 4 arguments, and one takes 5.  However I get an error along the lines of

```
Error C2780 ... OutOfPlaceReturn ... : expects 4 arguments - 5 provided.

... A bunch of template parameters ...

See declaration of ' ... ::OutOfPlaceReturn'
```

which references the line of the 4 argument method definition

In this case I'm trying to call the overload with 5 arguments, so I don't understand why the compiler thinks I want to call the function which only takes 4 arguments.

The full context is too complex to give the full code example, but suffice it to say this all takes place inside of a class template, which has lots of local `typedef`s, including `samp_type`, `const_samp`, `samp_vec`, etc.  These are all either typedefs of a template argument which holds a POD type, or a `std::array` of one of these POD types

```
typedef int_fast16_t                                fast_int;
typedef typename std::add_const< fast_int >::type   const_fast_int;

typedef samp_type (*func_type)(const_samp, const_samp);

template<func_type operation, const_fast_int strideA, const_fast_int strideB, const_fast_int strideOut>
static inline samp_vec OutOfPlaceReturn(const std::array<samp_type, strideA * vectorLen> &a,
                                        const_fast_int strideA,
                                        const std::array<samp_type, strideB * vectorLen> &b,
                                        const_fast_int strideB,
                                        const_fast_int strideOut)
{
    std::array<samp_type, vectorLen * strideOut> output;
    for(fast_int i = 0; i < vectorLen; ++i)
        output[i * strideOut] = operation(a[i * strideA], b[i * strideB]);
    return output;
}
template<func_type operation, const_fast_int strideA, const_fast_int strideOut>
static inline samp_vec OutOfPlaceReturn(const std::array<samp_type, strideA * vectorLen> &a,
                                        const_fast_int strideA,
                                        const_samp_ref b,
                                        const_fast_int strideOut)
{
    std::array<samp_type, vectorLen * strideOut> output;
    for(fast_int i = 0; i < vectorLen; ++i)
        output[i * strideOut] = operation(a[i * strideA], b);
    return output;
}
```

If I understand correctly, when calling a template function, you don't need to provide the template parameters which the compiler can deduce through function arguments, so the call looks like this

```
static samp_vec subtract(const_vec_ref a, const_fast_int strideA, const_vec_ref b, const_fast_int strideB, const_fast_int strideOut)
{   return OutOfPlaceReturn<MathClass::subtract>(a, strideA, b, strideB, strideOut);    }
```

So, is there something wrong with the way I'm calling these template methods? Is there something wrong with the way I'm expecting the compiler to resolve overloads?

**Edit**

I'm using VS2010. So far it's been pretty good with templates and C++11 data-types. Not sure if my compiler is acting sub-par

Comment: Don't think it explains the error, but it's not a great idea to have a template parameter `strideA` and a function parameter `strideA`.  You could probably ditch the function parameters and just use the template parameters inside the definitions.

Comment: I tried removing strideA, strideB and strideOut from the function argument. The compiler still complains but this time a little differently: `too many template arguments`. This seems to me to be fundamentally the same problem: The compiler can't figure out which template method I mean.

Comment: You seem to be confused about how template parameters work. You try to use non-type template, then redeclare them in the argument list and then don't pass them in the call. This is all very odd.

Comment: I seem to understand fundamentally how template parameters work. What I don't have is experience using them. I was trying to apply the constraint that the stride values be known at compile-time. I see how putting that information directly into the template parameters without removing them from the function signature is a little strange. Is that what was odd about it, or is there something else too? I can take any advice on better ways to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution is done only for templates that can be instantiated. This is part of why [`SFINAE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) works.

In your case, your 5 arg overload has an ambiguous `strideOut`. Is that a template parameter or not?

Comment: Actually the function parameter declarations of `strideOut` (it's there in both) are invalid, because the name of a template parameter shall not be redeclared within the template.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Now that I look at it, so is `strideA` and `strideB`. And the 4-arg version has pretty much the same problems with `strideOut` and `strideA`. I guess the compiler just gave up.

Comment: Also he appears to want `strideA * vectorLen` to be deduced, perhaps by implicit division. Best advice might be to take it one step at a time :)

Comment: vectorLen is a template argument for the class that contains all these methods. @MSalters why is strideOut ambiguous?

Comment: @xaviersjs: You're trying to pass `strideOut` both as a template parameter and as a regular parameter.